# Python Socket Programming - Simulate a radio stream with multiple clients using threads

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I've been trying to write a python program that simulates a radio web stream, but I'm not quite sure how to do it properly. To do so, I would like to have the program continuously "playing" the musics even if there are no clients connected, so it would simulate a "live" radio where you connect and listen to whatever is playing.

What I have now is a server/client relation with TCP basic socket programming, the server side has a producer thread that was supposed to keep reading the music, and on-demand consumer threads that should send the audio frame to the client, that plays it with PyAudio. The problem is probably in the way the data is shared between threads.

First I've tried to do it with a single **Queue**, but as the client reads data from the queue, this data is removed and if I have multiple clients connected, that will make the music skip some frames.

Then I've tried to create a fixed number (10) of **Queue** objects that would be used for each client, with the producer thread feeding every queue, but each client would create a consumer thread of its own and read only from the queue "assigned" to it with a control variable. The problem here is: if there are any queues not being consumed (if I have only one client connected, for example), the **Queue.put()** method will block because these queues are full. How do I keep all queues "running" and synchronized even when they are not being used?

This is where I am now, and any advice is appreciated. I am not an experienced programmer yet, so please be patient with me. I believe **Queue** is not the recommended IPC method in this case, but if there is a way to use it, let me know.

Below is the code I have for now:

server.py

```
#TCP config omitted

#Producer Thread
def readTheMusics(queue):
    #Control variable to keep looping through 2 music files
    i=1
   
    while i < 3:
       
        fname = "music" + str(i) + ".wav"
        wf = wave.open(fname, 'rb')
        data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
        
        while data:
              
            for k in range (10):
                
                queue[k].put(data)
              
            data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

        wf.close()
        i += 1
        if i==3:
            i=1

#Consumer Thread
def connection(connectionSocket, addr, queue, index):
    while True:
        data = queue[index-1].get(True)
        connectionSocket.send(data)
    connectionSocket.close()        

def main():
    i = 1
    #Queue(1) was used to prevent an infinite queue and therefore a memory leak
    queueList = [Queue(1) for j in range(10)]
    th2 = threading.Thread(target=musicReading, args=(queueList, ))
    th2.start()
    while True:
        
        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
        
        print("connected - id {}".format(i))
        
        th = threading.Thread(target=connection, args=(connectionSocket, addr, queueList, i))
        
        th.start()
      
        i = i + 1
                    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: A queue is not the right answer.  Your connection thread should just store the current set of connected sockets in a list.  Then, every time you read a chunk from the wave file, you just do `for sock in socketlist:` / `sock.send(data)`.

Comment: Hello Tim! How could I get the data from the reading thread this way?

Comment: Do the send IN the reading thread.  You don't need a connection thread.  When `accept` returns, add the socket to a global list.  You'll need to check for "send" failing so you can removed closed sockets from the list.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'm still having some problems, don't know if I'm doing it right. I've tested it with 2 simultaneous clients, and the music is still not synchronized. Maybe the `send(data)` method is not instant, or something else, and the for loop gets stuck there... Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "synchronized"?  There are always going to be variable network delays.

Comment: Hi Tim, it was my mistake. I've tested it remotely with a friend and it worked perfectly, I thought it was skipping frames, but it wasn't. Thanks a million, your answer guided me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim Roberts' comments were enough to make it work.